# AUC and difference between vote and predict() in randomForest in R

Tags: r, random-forest, auc

I've got a problem regarding predict() function and $votes in r when i try to calcualte AUC and draw ROC curve. My model is randomForest and code looks like this:

```
rf_optimal = randomForest(Revenue~., data=train, ntree=250, mtry=4, do.trace=T)
```

The ROC curve on a train set I get using the code below looks like this:

```
roc(train$Revenue, rf_optimal$votes[,2], 
    plot = TRUE, legacy.axes = TRUE, percent = TRUE,
    xlab = "False Positive Percentage", ylab = "True positive percentage",
    col = "blue", lwd = 3, print.auc = TRUE, print.auc.y = 45)
```

[Roc curve using $votes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TggLL.png)

And when I use predict() function instead the AUC equals to 100%

```
roc(train$Revenue, predict(rf_optimal,newdata = train, type = "prob")[,2], 
    plot = TRUE, legacy.axes = TRUE, percent = TRUE,
    xlab = "False Positive Percentage", ylab = "True positive percentage",
    col = "blue", lwd = 3, print.auc = TRUE, print.auc.y = 45)
```

[Roc curve using predcit()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BxMV.png)

What is the difference between those two aproaches? Is it possible to obtain such a value of AUC measure at all, or does it mean that the model is overfitted? AUC for the test set is about 90%.

Comment: It is possible to obtain an AUC of 1, if the fit on the train dataset is perfect; it is difficult to say what is going on without seeing your data. How many records and features do you have?

Comment: The train set consists of 8543 rows and it is 70% of the whole dataset. There are 14 variables - 6 numercial and 8 factors. The target variable is  imbalanced but even after oversampling the test set AUC is equal to 1. The dataset is here https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Online+Shoppers+Purchasing+Intention+Dataset My modifications to original data are dropping ExitRate and replacing number of pages viewed and number of seconds spent on each type of site to average time spent on each type of site during session.

Comment: I expect your random forest is able to (almost) perfectly separate the `TRUE` and `FALSE` cases, hence giving an AUC of 1. You can inspect this with `table(train$Revenue, predict(rf_optimal,newdata = train, type = "prob")[,2])` and seeing whether at some point there are only zeros in the `FALSE` column. In other words, as the difference between the train and test performance is very large, you are overfitting on your train set. Try removing some variables or reducing the number of trees.

Comment: Yes, there are many points with only zeros in false column. Even after reducing number of trees to 20 there is still AUC equal to 100%. Is it possible that the roc curve should be drawn using rf_optimal$votes[,2] not the predcit function? The results are very different